# How to select values which are not present in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

So I have 2 tables
`fee_types` which consists of all the fee types

```
+-------------+---------------+
| fee_type_id | fee_type_name |
+-------------+---------------+
|           1 | Caution Fee   |
|           2 | Lab Fee       |
|           3 | Admission Fee |
|           4 | Term Fee I    |
|           5 | Term Fee II   |
|           6 | Computer Fee  |
+-------------+---------------+
```

and `paid_fees` which consists of the fees a student has paid

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+---------------+
| student_name | student_id | fee_type_id | fee_type_name |
+--------------+------------+-------------+---------------+
| ABC          |       4601 |           1 | Caution Fee   |
| ABC          |       4601 |           2 | Lab Fee       |
| ABC          |       4601 |           4 | Term Fee I    |
| ABC          |       4601 |           5 | Term Fee II   |
| XYZ          |       4602 |           3 | Admission Fee |
| XYZ          |       4602 |           1 | Caution Fee   |
| XYZ          |       4602 |           2 | Lab Fee       |
| XYZ          |       4602 |           4 | Term Fee I    |
| XYZ          |       4602 |           6 | Computer Fee  |
+--------------+------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Now I want to display which type of fees a student has not paid. 
For eg student ABC has not paid `Admission`, `Computer` fees and student XYZ has not paid `Term II` fees. I want the result table to look like this

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+---------------+
| student_name | student_id | fee_type_id | fee_type_name |
+--------------+------------+-------------+---------------+
| ABC          |       4601 |           1 | Admission Fee |
| ABC          |       4601 |           2 | Computer Fee  |
| XYZ          |       4602 |           3 | Term II       |
+--------------+------------+-------------+---------------+
```

What can I do to obtain it? I have tried several solutions from StackOverflow but none of them work. Can someone suggest what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cross join the list of students with the list of possible fees, and then use `not exists` to exhibit those that do not appear in `paid_fees`:

```
select s.*, f.*
from (select distinct student_name, student_id from paid_fees) s
cross join fee_types f
where not exists(
    select 1 
    from paid_fees pf 
    where pf.student_id = s.student_id and pf.fee_type_id = f.fee_type_id
)
```

In a real life situation, you would have a separate table to store the students, that you could use in place o the `select distint` subquery:

```
select s.*, f.*
from students s
cross join fee_types f
where not exists(
    select 1 
    from paid_fees pf 
    where pf.student_id = s.student_id and pf.fee_type_id = f.fee_type_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks man, It Woked, I will mark the answer as correct, Can you explain what select 1 does?